# Connect Excel to Oracle database: invalid username/password: logon denied error

Tags: excel, vba, database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to connect excel to a Oracle database for the first time, but it throws the "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied" error every time I try to run the code below. The user name and password are definitely correct.

```
Sub test()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String

'ConnectionString
Const hostName = "12.3.4.567"
Const portNo = "1531"
Const srvSID = "mySID"
Const usrID = "myUser"
Const usrPwd = "myPassword"

strDriver = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;"
strParams = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=MyVbaApp)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" + hostName + ")(PORT=" + portNo + ")))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=" + srvSID + ")));"
strUser = "UID=" + usrID + ";PWD=" + usrPwd + ";"
ConnectionString = strDriver + strParams + strUser

cnn.Open ConnectionString
End Sub
```

I can connect to the database from SQL Developer and Dbeaver with no problems. I don't really know what could be the problem, I tried to connect to a db with a  full lower case pwd and username in order to discard that possible issue.

I would be very thankful for any help since idk much about this topic, thanks!

Comment: The problem is that Oracle disagrees that the username and password are correct.  Maybe you have the correct username and password but you are connecting to the wrong database.  Posting the SQL Developer connection string that works might help someone identify what is incorrect.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/tns-less-connection-string/  looks like your connection string is not using "User Id" and "Password" but "UID" and "PWD" ?

Comment: that worked!! I have had already tried with a lot of different connection strings and the solution was really simple. Thanks you so much for the help!